# Using callback function with parameters between components

Tags: angular, fullcalendar

Does anyone can tell me how to change this part of **scheduler.component.ts**:

```
events: (start: any, end: any, timezone: any, callback: any) => {
                    callback(this.events);
                }
```

and this part of **cal.component.ts**:

```js
 this.events = this.getEvents();
```

so I could in function getEvents() in **cal.component.ts**, call method:
*this.BookingService.getBookings(this.ip, **start, end**).subscribe(*

instead of
*this.BookingService.getBookings(this.ip).subscribe(*

### All code below is working right now as it should

but I don't want to load all bookings if calendar is showing range from the start date to the end date. Parameters start and end are correctly set in scheduler.component.ts.

**Below I put only important parts of the app:**

cal.component.html

```html
  <div>
    <ds3-schedule (onEventClick)="handleEventClick($event)" (onEventResize)="resizeEvent($event)" (onEventDragStop)="saveEvent($event)"
      (onDayClick)="showDialog($event)" editable="true" defaultView="timelineMonth" [header]="header" [resourceColumns]="resourceColumns"
      [resources]="resources" [(events)]="events" [defaultDate]="defaultDate" [aspectRatio]="1.2" [resourceAreaWidth]="85"
      titleFormat="YYYY-MM-DD dddd" [contentHeight]=330 nowIndicator="true" scrollTime="00:00" locale="pl"
      (onViewRender)="onViewRender($event)" (onEventLoading)="loadingEvents($event)">
    </ds3-schedule>
  </div>
```

scheduler.component.ts

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'ds3-schedule',
    styles: ['./cal.component.css'],
    template: '<div [attr.style]="style" [attr.class]="styleClass"></div>'
})

export class SchedulerComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, DoCheck {

    @Input() events: any[];

ngAfterViewInit() {
         this.schedule = jQuery(this.el.nativeElement);
       
        if (this.schedule.fullCalendar) {
            this.schedule.fullCalendar({

events: (start: any, end: any, timezone: any, callback: any) => {
                    callback(this.events);
                }

}
```

cal.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'ds-schedule',
  styles: ['./cal.component.css'],
  templateUrl: './cal.component.html',
  //changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [
    CustomerService,
    CalService,
    BookingService
  ]
})

ngOnInit() {
       this.optionConfig = {}
       this.header = {
         left: 'prev,next today',
         center: 'title',
         right: 'timelineMonth, timelineYear'
       };

       this.events = this.getEvents();
       this.resources = this.getResources();
}

getEvents(): MyEvent[] {
    var events: MyEvent[] = [];
    this.ipservice.getIP().subscribe(
      d => {
        this.ip = d;
        this.BookingService.getBookings(this.ip).subscribe(
          data => {
            this.bookings = data;
            this.bookings.forEach(booking => {
              events.push(this.bookingToEvent(booking));
            });
          }
        )
      }
    );
    return events;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the `events` function is triggered when the user clicks prev/next or switches views, you will need to get the events again by sending a request with the start/end filters, or if the Backend doesn't support it, you will have to make it on the client side.

I'm not sure what is the relation between the `CalComponent` and the `SchedulerComponent` (Parent to child relation maybe?), but either they will need to communicate with each other using the EventEmitters or exporting the `getEvents` function into a service and call it wherever you want.

Example of the service solution:

In scheduler.component.ts

```
events: (start: any, end: any, timezone: any, callback: any) => {
  this.myService.getEvents(start, end);
  callback(this.events);
}
```

---

In my.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService{

  constructor() { }

  getEvents(start?: number, end?: number){
    var events: MyEvent[] = [];
    this.ipservice.getIP().subscribe(
    d => {
      this.ip = d;
      this.BookingService.getBookings(this.ip, start, end).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.bookings = data;
          this.bookings.forEach(booking => {
            events.push(this.bookingToEvent(booking));
          });
        }
      )
    });
    return events;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to handle the `undefined` values for `start` and `end` in the `BookingService`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, but problem might be somewhere else. I tried to emit event and that looked promising on the beginning. In scheduler.component I added:

```js
events: (start: any, end: any, timezone: any, callback: any) => {
                        this.onCallendarChange.emit( {start, end});
                        callback(this.events);
                }
```

then in my html view I added (onCallendarChange):

```html
<ds3-schedule (onEventClick)="handleEventClick($event)" (onEventResize)="resizeEvent($event)" (onEventDragStop)="saveEvent($event)"
      (onDayClick)="showDialog($event)" editable="true" defaultView="timelineMonth" [header]="header" [resourceColumns]="resourceColumns"
      [resources]="resources" [(events)]="events" [defaultDate]="defaultDate" [aspectRatio]="1.2" [resourceAreaWidth]="85"
      titleFormat="YYYY-MM-DD dddd" [contentHeight]=330 nowIndicator="true" scrollTime="00:00" locale="pl"
      (onViewRender)="onViewRender($event)" (onEventLoading)="loadingEvents($event)" (onCallendarChange)="onCallendarChange($event)">
    </ds3-schedule>
```

and in cal.component:

```js
ngOnInit() {
       this.events = this.getEvents(moment().date(1),moment().date(31));
}

onCallendarChange(event: any): void{
    this.start = event.start;
    this.end = event.end;
    this.events = this.getEvents(this.start,this.end);
  }
```

The effect is as follows:

- after the page has been loaded I have records for the current month
- after month change event is emitted and in cal.component I can see new values
- values in this.events in scheduler.component after callback(this.events) don't change. Still have results from ngOnInit()

I tried to reinitialize **this.events** with new empty object but then I got infinite loop and records starts loading and resetting all the time. I could see on my page that after month change I got new data, but I can't stop this loop of events.

I tried also second approach (through service), but result is similar. Infinite loop.

This two components don't use each other directly. They are connected by html view.

Answer (score 0):

well I'm in this hell for a while and trying different approaches. This is with Observable, but it didn't change too much.

### scheduler.component.ts

```js
events: (start: any, end: any, timezone: any, callback: any) => {
                            this.getEvents(start,end).subscribe( evnt =>{
                                console.log(evnt);       <---- screenshot no. 1
                                //this.events = evnt;    <---- this makes endless loop
                                callback(evnt);          <---- this don't change value in calendar
                            });
                }
```

[screenshot no. 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm0ES.png)

This works but only loads data during initialization of the cal.component. Can't reload them later.

```js
events: (start: any, end: any, timezone: any, callback: any) => {
                            console.log(this.events);       <---- screenshot no. 2
                            callback(this.events);
```

[screenshot no. 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfITq.png)

as you can see variable **this.events** has Array(12)[MyEvenc,...] and evnt Array(0)[] but both have the same values inside. The different is that when I use callback(this.events) I can see results in the calendar and not when I use callback(evnt)

This is endless loop:

```js
events: (start: any, end: any, timezone: any, callback: any) => {
                            this.getEvents(start,end).subscribe( evnt =>{
                                this.events = evnt;    <---- this makes endless loop
                            });
                }


Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'events: [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]'. Current value: 'events: '.
```

It seems that events:(start: any, end: any, timezone: any, callback: any) => { ... is the only place where I can get **start** and **end** but it's not the place where I can change value of **this.events**.